# TestCleanup() Implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How would I write the [TestCleanup()] method for these [TestMethod()]'s.

I have 11 of the following:

When run individually they pass, when not run at the same time the first passes

```
[TestMethod()]
public void SplitTdsNameTest_SimpleValidName2()
{
    string tdsName = "Mr Daniel George Trunley";
    MemberName expected = new MemberName("Mr", "Daniel George", "Trunley");
    MemberName actual;
    actual = TdsTransformer.SplitTdsName(tdsName);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}


[TestMethod()]
public void SplitTdsNameTest_SimpleValidName3()
{
    string tdsName = "Daniel George Trunley";
    MemberName expected = new MemberName("", "", "Daniel George Trunley");
    MemberName actual;
    actual = TdsTransformer.SplitTdsName(tdsName);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

MemberName:

```
public struct MemberName
{
    public string Title;
    public string FirstNames;
    public string LastNames;

    public MemberName(string title, string firstNames, string lastNames)            
    {            
        Title = title;
        FirstNames = firstNames;
        LastNames = lastNames;
    }
}
```

SplitTds:

```
public MemberName SplitTdsName(string tdsName)
    {
        return NameSplitter.Splitter(tdsName);
    }
```

Splitter:

```
public static MemberName Splitter(string fullName)
    {
        nameInFull = fullName;
        SetAllowedTitles();
        SplitNamesAndRemovePeriods();
        SetTitles();
        MemberName splitName = new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames);
        return splitName;
    }
```

Comment: `TdsTransformer`, is that an *instance* or a class reference (so is `SplitTdsName` a static or instance method)? Is `SplitTdsName` holding onto old data? Have you provided proper equality implementations inside `MemberName`? There is not enough to go by given your edit.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram is that enough information? Or would it require more?

Comment: I agree with Austin in his answer, I'm worried about the static method and the global state involved. I'm also worried about the struct, it's mutability, etc. I think you should probably revisit your design.

Comment: I inherited this design and unfortunately can't change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what's provided, it doesn't look like any cleanup is necessary.

If there's a `TestInitialize` method, just undo what's done there.

If `TdsTransformer.SplitTdsName` stores any internal state, you'll have to clear that as well.  Though if it *does*, it likely shouldn't be a static method.

Based on the edits, these two methods worry me:

```
    SetAllowedTitles();
    SetTitles();
```

They imply there is internal state which, in my opinion, is *very bad* for a static class.  This is likely the issue you are seeing with consecutive tests not passing.

To correct these *and* keep it static, have them return values instead of storing in static members:

```
    var allowedTitles = SetAllowedTitles(fullName);
    var names = SplitNamesAndRemovePeriods(fullName);  //likely a struct or class with first/last names
    var titles = SetTitles(allowedTitles);
```